# What is considered a poisonous attack?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am going to get ancient shrouded armor and one of the pieces has 100% poison resistance. The question is, which of enemy attacks are considered poisoning attacks in Skyrim? The only thing that crosses my mind are frostbite spider attacks, but I'm not even sure they are considered poisonous.

Any ideas?

Comment: I forget if they are in Skyrim but there were Poison Gas traps in Oblivion that had no effect if you resisted poison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fairly good [list of poison damage sources](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Poison_Damage) available on the wiki. Sources include

- Frostbite Spiders
- Chaurus
- Some Falmer weapons
- Dart traps in ruins
- Poison Bloom plants in the Dawnguard DLC
- The Main Quest Boss in the Dragonborn DLC
- [Spriggans](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Spriggan) (But not the Burnt Spriggans in the Dragonborn DLC)

Additionally, any enemy who uses a poison item to poison their blade will also count as poison damage.

Answer (score 2):

The spiders, being venemous, can poison you. There are also poison gas traps. The Shrouded Armor will work on those, but it won't work on the gas in Calcelmo's lab in Markarth.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from Frostbite Spiders and Chaurus, Skyrim simply doesn't have a lot of poisonous critters. Humanoid enemies won't use poisons on you in the base game, which means that poison resistance is of minimal benefit.

However, there is one family of critter that deals *lots* of poison damage: Spriggans have a channeled Poison damage spell which can prove quite deadly to low-level characters. With 100% poison resistance, you can whack these natural denizens with ease (especially the ones around the Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary in the woods around Falkreath).

Answer (score 1):

The Afflicted also use a poison breath type attack but it can be blocked by magic resistance like dragon breath, centurion steam, etc since the game considers them to be magic attacks.